# PHP session not saving data

Tags: php, session

I am trying to save login attempt count to php session variable but finaly i decided to ask here

Code always returns 1

**here is my "not working" logic in code:**

```
$sessionSecret = strval(md5(hash("sha512", random_int(1000000, 9999999))));
session_name($sessionSecret);
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', FALSE);
ini_set('session.use_cookies', TRUE);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', TRUE);
ini_set('session.use_strict_mode', TRUE);
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', TRUE);
ini_set('session.cookie_secure', FALSE);
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', FALSE);
ini_set('session.cache_limiter', 'private_no_expire');
ini_set('session.hash_function', 'sha512');
session_start();
session_regenerate_id();

// login attempt checker

$check = TRUE ? !isset($_SESSION['login_attemp']): FALSE;

if ($check) {
    $_SESSION['login_attemp'] = 0;
}

if (isset($_SESSION['login_attemp'])) {
    $_SESSION['login_attemp'] += 1;
    echo $_SESSION['login_attemp']; // result is always "1"
}
```

Comment: If you use a random session name each time, you won't be in the same session the next time the script is called.

Comment: Tell me if I am correct this happens before you logged in right and you are counting from that specific account . So if you are going to check the attempt login from that account you don't need a session for that . What you will need is just `if(userExist) { //add the count and if(userAttemptLogIn > 3){// ban it's account for like 5 minutes ; }}`